# Transitions for NSView in Interface Builder

Tags: objective-c, interface-builder, transition

In Interface Builder there is **View Effects Inspector**. For NSView one can find **Transitions** setting there with their options.
What is the correct way to use this setting? Having this in IB does not suppose lots of coding to implement, am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this appeared to be really easy. One has to use **animator** property of subview to peform transition. For example, if parent view of "mySubview" has transition subviews option set up to some transition style,

`[[mySubview animator] removeFromSuperview];`

will use specified transition to remove itself from superview.